# Loading c library from c# with pinvoke on dotnet core

Tags: c#, c, .net-core, pthreads, pinvoke

I built the following c library:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sched.h>

int attachCurrentThreadToCore(int core);

int main(void) {
    return 0;
}

int attachCurrentThreadToCore(int core) {

    pthread_t thread;

    thread = pthread_self();

    cpu_set_t set;

    CPU_ZERO(&set);

    CPU_SET(core, &set);

    return pthread_setaffinity_np(thread, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &set);
}
```

and now im trying to pinvoke attachCurrentThreadToCore.

This is my pinvoke test code:

```
    [DllImport("/home/anon/Documents/RadFramework/RadFramework.Libraries.Threading/src/TestProject1/bin/Debug/net5.0/pthreadWrapper")]
    
    private static extern int attachCurrentThreadToCore(int core);
    
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        attachCurrentThreadToCore(0);
        while (true)
        {
        }
    }
```

Now iwould expect core 1 on my machine to spin in the while loop. Instead i receive this exception when pinvoking:

Unable to load shared library '/home/anon/Documents/RadFramework/RadFramework.Libraries.Threading/src/TestProject1/bin/Debug/net5.0/pthreadWrapper' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: /home/anon/Documents/RadFramework/RadFramework.Libraries.Threading/src/TestProject1/bin/Debug/net5.0/pthreadWrapper: cannot dynamically load position-independent executable

I think it boils down to "cannot dynamically load position-independent executable".

Is there anything else i need to do when compiling my c library?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What was the compile command  you used to build your c "library" (executable?)?

Comment: make all 
Building file: ../src/pthreadWrapper.c
Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/pthreadWrapper.d" -MT"src/pthreadWrapper.o" -o "src/pthreadWrapper.o" "../src/pthreadWrapper.c"
Finished building: ../src/pthreadWrapper.c
 
Building target: pthreadWrapper
Invoking: Cross GCC Linker
gcc  -o "pthreadWrapper"  ./src/pthreadWrapper.o   -lpthread
Finished building target: pthreadWrapper

Comment: @omajid This is my gcc build output in eclipse :)

Comment: Usually, you will need to include the library as native library into your project and make it copy to the output folder "bin". Then you simply include it relative to your Assembly. Don't forget the ".dll"-Suffix.

Comment: I tried  again and it did not make a difference, sorry. I think its about the compilation process of my lib.

Comment: Are you sure that you can use pthreads from .net safely? And doesn't .net have a way to set thread affinity?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thread affinity is not supported affinity per process is. The windows implementation looks different and uses https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadaffinitymask but in my linux environment pthread is the way to go. I need to set affinity per thread for high performance needs ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the build artifact in eclipse from executable to library:

[image: Eclipse]

This results in this build output:

make all
Building file: ../src/pthreadWrapper.c
Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/pthreadWrapper.d" -MT"src/pthreadWrapper.o" -o "src/pthreadWrapper.o" "../src/pthreadWrapper.c"
Finished building: ../src/pthreadWrapper.c

Building target: libPthreadWrapper.so
Invoking: Cross GCC Linker
gcc -shared -o "libPthreadWrapper.so"  ./src/pthreadWrapper.o   -lpthread
Finished building target: libPthreadWrapper.so

After that the pinvoke is working.